# Объединение двух Elements

Tags: doc, android, jsoup, select

Привет всем.
Есть две переменные Elements

```
title1 = doc.select("IPList");
title2 = doc.select("Description");
```

Тут я вывожу одну из них в листвью

```
for (Element titles : title1) {

                titleList.add(titles.text());
        }
```

Подскажите, можно ли их объединить, чтобы их содержимое выводилось вместе, разделенное знаком пробела(\n)?

Я пытался это сделать так

```
 String test =  title1.toString() + "/n" + title2.toString();
            Element elem = new Element(null, test);
            title0.add(elem);
```

Но происходит падение в строке

```
 Element elem = new Element(null, test);
```

Comment: Читайте мануал, хотя бы javadoc, элемент создается не так. А вам, судя по всему, нужен:

    title0.append(test);

Comment: Тоже падение в этой строке.

Comment: по вашему описанию проблема не воспроизводится. приведите более полный участок кода, который приводит к падению, а также сообщение об ошибке из logcat. это существенно сократило бы время гадания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то для вывода в ListView советую переопределить ArrayAdapter. Вот довольно хорошая статья на эту тему. [тыц](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)